# Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I'm new to DevOps world and I'm completely lost and confused.

Well, I wanna make a Django app with Postgres database and with Gunicorn and Nginx but I wanna dockerize everything.

I know that Django has venv, this virtual environment for development so I'm wondering whether I should use that on my local machine or just configure Gunicorn and Nginx and use exactly the same images and environments on development and production so that also means that there's only one .env file.

Is it a good solution? Because I don't want to use venv on production.

Comment: If you want to use docker you don't need venv. You can use different env files for different deploys.

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander can I use venv with Docker? Is it a good solution?

Comment: you almost certainly do not want to use venv with docker!  it is technically possible to use it, but venv is more useful for local development than deployment.  the example at https://hub.docker.com/_/django/ is a good place to start

Comment: `virtualenv` is an extremely useful tool for isolating Python environments.

When using containers, however, it is less useful, as we are already provided with an isolated environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual environment helps you keep dependencies required by different projects  separate. Hence, it makes sense to use a venv when you are having multiple projects on a single system with varied dependencies.

While using docker, you try to keep one container limited to one project. While this is technically possible to create a virtual environment inside a docker container but it really isn't a good thing. With docker, you already have a complete different "environment" for all your projects.

Also, keeping your point of production in mind, it is always advisable to use containers like docker.

You can have multiple containers working together for your project, like postgres nginx and web_app, using one or different .envs, totally depending upon the way you want to orchestrate in your docker-compose.yml